# Is there a way to detect network traffic encrypted by MACsec?

Tags: encryption, wireshark

We are going to analyse some traffic on our network. Some streams are encrypted and we know that the encrypted protocols aren't IPsec.
We suspect it is using MACsec and we are looking for some way to detect that.

Is there a way to detect the type of packet encryption?

Comment: It would help if you could upload the pcap file with the suspect network flow, but link a encryption type to an application probably is not possible from my point of view.

Comment: I can't do this because the information is classified

Comment: anonymize the mac and the IP thats easy with tcpreplay :)

Comment: by the way macsec is a standard protocol with extension headers so you can detect that even with wireshark, check out https://www.cloudshark.org/captures/653a5b97a1dd

Comment: Yes this is the same package we received, only the 802.1AE Security tag is missing in our packages,But the rest is exactly the same . tnx @camp0

Comment: If you dont have that header then is not macsec, is other thing that you need to figure out. Without the pcap file is going to be very difficult, try to see if some of the DPI tools can discover what it is (snort, suricata, ndpi, aiengine, moloc, etc...)

Comment: Classified, or confidential? If it really is classified, then you shouldn't be posting this here.

Comment: That's why I didn't share any files here :) . @forest

Comment: One way to detect is if you control the connection via MKA. One of EAP methods contain MKA as the final stage that distributes the SAK for MACsec. This key can be used by the DPI to filter out the ongoing frames. But remember that the decryption requires identifying the correct packet number. Packet number is used by the MACsec in generating the IVs used in encryption.